# Why are some phonemic sounds not included in their language’s phonemic inventory?

Tags: phonology

Sorry for the weird wording and the beginner question,

I’m trying to ask why, as an example in Finnish, do we not put the long vowels in the vowel chart while Māori’s long vowels are represented in its vowel chart (according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start out, I think it's worth mentioning that it's debated whether phonemes are real.

If phonemes are imaginary, there might be no greater reason than whimsy and happenstance for listing one language's phonemes one way and another language's phonemes in a different way. So it is a good idea to have some skepticism about the meaningfulness of such notational (or theoretical) differences.

But if we assume that phonemes do exist (or at least that there are some non-arbitrary reasons for saying that languages have one set of phonemes rather than another), we can imagine that in some languages phonetic long vowels might be phonemic sequences (consisting of the same vowel phoneme repeated twice in a single syllable), while in other languages phonetic long vowels might be a single vowel phoneme with twice the length of a short vowel phoneme.

However, it is not uncommon for there to be debate about which of these analyses is better for a language.

The Wikipedia article "[Finnish language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_language#Phonology)" actually does show Finnish as having 16 monophthongal vowel phonemes (8 short and 8 long), but mentions the possibility of an alternative analysis. I'm not sure where you see a chart for Finnish that doesn't put long vowels in the vowel chart.

Comment: Thank you for answering! The Finnish vowel chart I was talking about is the one in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_phonology), it does mention that there's distinction between long and short vowels, but says that they count as two successive vowel phonemes. I think it'd get too specific if I asked where we're drawing the line, with Reo Māori's vowel inventory being a bit different. I mainly asked this question because I wanted to know why I can't find much written about this long-short distinction in Turkish.

Comment: Finnish is often claimed to be mora-timed (like Japanese), which may have something to do with it – if long vowels are two morae, it makes sense to consider them two vowels as well.

Comment: phonemes aren't real? Must be those weird lurkers....